# Where is Coded UI Test in Vs 2010 premium

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I was trying to add coded UI test project to an existing project in Visual studio 2010 premium. I right click in the solution explorer and click Add new Item and it doesnot show any option of Coded UI test. Is there anything I need to install so that I can see those project options?

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it. We have to first add test project and then right click that project to add Coded UI test.

- Lalith

Comment: If this is considered as an answer, you better mark it as answer. So others can benefit it.

Comment: Can you please add some screenshot because I am not able to get an option to add Coded UI test anywhere.